# Static fields and objects broadcasting analogs in Koin way

Tags: android, kotlin, static, koin

Let's imagine we have some data that should be used in the couple different activities. And some objects that should be used in different activities without redurant initialization (less code and less CPU usage).

For example, we can initialize public static `SoundPool` object and load sounds to it in the first activity, and then play sounds via this SoundPool in the second one.

Some people told me that this is poor way to code. But they are also did not told me how to do it correctly.

I tried to find some clever ways for this. I hope we can use `Koin` to inject any previous static objects to use it in our projects. But there are no information how to inject `SoundPool` object to reach "Best practices" way.

The question:

> How can we (can we?) use Koin to inject special objects (like a SoundPool)?

Minor question:

> There are also some static fields in my static class that I previously used to broadcast user settings (for example volume settings). How can I substitute it to reach the "Best practices" way?

Comment: "we have some data that should be used in the couple different activities" -- perhaps they should be a single activity with multiple fragments. "But there are no information how to inject SoundPool object" -- `SoundPool` is not a special object. You can inject one the same way that you might inject anything else, such as the sample `Presenter` shown in [the Koin documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/get-instances).

Comment: @CommonsWare I am looking to make it single activity app in the future, but my question was about multi activity apps. Then I mean that `SoundPool` gives id of each sound has been loaded (we use it to play sounds), but we cannot pass it if we initialize it this way, isn't it?

Comment: "but we cannot pass it if we initialize it this way, isn't it?" -- sorry, but I do not understand that question. If it is working for you as a Java `static` field or Kotlin top-level property, it should work for you as a Koin `single`.